# If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, then $Y \subset A$ and $Y \cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ denote a metric space, and let $A$ and $B$ be 2 open nonempty subsets such that $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. If $Y \subset X$ is a connected subspace of $X$ then either $Y \subset A$ with $Y \cap B = \emptyset$ or $Y \subset B$ with $Y \cap A = \emptyset$.

My attempt of a proof is the following.

The two sets $A$ and $B$ are separable, if $Y \subset A$ and $Y \subset B$ then $Y=X$, but $X$ is not connected so $Y \subset A$ or $Y \subset B$. Let then $Y \subset A$.

Assume $Y \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then we can find an element in both $Y$ and $B$. Take $b \in Y \cap B$. Since $Y \subset A$ then $b \in A \cap B \Longrightarrow b \in A$. But this means that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, which contradicts our original assumption, thus if $Y \subset A$ then $Y \cap B = \emptyset$.

I'm not quite sold on this proof, so is this right?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I follow your logic, but how about: Let $U=Y\cap A$ and $V=Y\cap B$. Then both are open and closed sets in $Y$  and if $Y$ is connected, one of them must be empty.